# Serverless lambda function with nested routes

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a simple serverless lambda function which works fine like

```
functions:
  consumer:
    name: consumer
    handler: consumer/create.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /create
          method: post
```

Here I can make request on the `/create` endpoint.

I would like to have nested structure here. Everything under `consumer` should have endpoint like `/consumer/create` without adding `/consumer` in every path.

I went through the documentation of serverless but didn't find it.
Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a little late for an answer but maybe this can help someone.

The only way I found that allows nested routes without declaring them manually was this one:

```
functions:
  consumer:
    name: consumer
    handler: consumer/create.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: "*"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).